# Mutt Configuration Based on Current Hostname

Tags: mutt, neomutt

I am specifically writing this from the perspective of running Mutt from multiple hosts, but a single source-code-controlled configuration file. Leave it to the devops side that "all" host configurations are being kept adequately in-sync.

So, basically, I want a specific mailbox configuration, effectively based on host type, but more generically, based solely on the hostname command. Essentially, I want the default mailbox to be "correct" for a given host (generally /var/mail/$user for Linux hosts), but I have already defined hotkeys for Mailbox 1-3 that default to hotkeys (basically F2, F# and F4 are the IMAPS mailboxes, and the default is the local system default).

How would you set this up? Currently, I can switch between mailboxes with the proper hotkeys. But, how do I base muttrc "decisions" based on the hostname in which mutt has been run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution should work with mutt and neomutt. The idea is to put host specific configuration in separate files and source them in main configuration file. See example below.

Files:

- `~/.neomutt/neomuttrc` main config file
- `~/.neomutt/neomuttrc.host1` host specific config file
- `~/.neomutt/neomuttrc.host2` host specific config file

Content of *~/.neomutt/neomuttrc*

```
# Your main confing file. Here ale all the shared settings. 
# …
# source host specific config
source ~/.neomutt/neomuttrc.`hostname`
```

Comment: Thanks... I guess the "old and simple" works.